# Mariadb - Blob data import works only in the same database of the dump

Tags: linux, mysql, mariadb

### I need to move my PHP webapp from the test-vps to the production-vps

So I've done a full dump of the test-DB in this way:

```
mysqldump -u root -p  --hex-blob --opt --net_buffer_length=10000k DataBase > database.sql
```

then I've tried to import that dump on my production vps via mysqldump and it seems to work but... all the longblob field are empty!!! 
Another test I've done was  execute a single query via Adminer... same result!

my database engine is Mariadb-server-5.3.9 on both the vps .

[here](http://pastebin.com/kgG0yu4i) a sample dump data from the test-db on "pastebin"

of course I maked a new database on my test-vps and if I try to import the dump it works like a charm

Thanks in advance for the help and my apologize for my English

Comment: I can't understand! on the test server i can correctly restore the dump file !

Answer (score 0):

Was a problem related with version of MariaDB.
After an update at the 10 on both the vps works like a charm.